# Is a preview of [preview-pane] enough?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a new tag [preview-pane](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview-pane) on a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1190794/how-can-i-add-default-preview-for-files-in-explorer) about the Windows Explorer preview pane, and would like to get community input on the tag.  I thought we had either this tag or [preview-panel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preview-panel) previously and that it was removed as too meta, but I can't find any history on it.

Preview panes do have some common characteristics, but I suspect that questions about preview panes will be pretty specific to the applicable software.

- Are preview panes enough of a concept that the tag is useful, at least as a subject clarifier, or is it too meta?
- If this tag is too meta, does it deserve a dedicated tag as a sub-tag on specific applications, or is it too granular and the application tag is enough?

Answer (score 2):

Preview panes require the interaction of the shell file viewer and either built-in file handlers or the format's default application to work properly.

File viewers for operating systems besides Windows also offer preview panel ability.

For these reasons I believe this tag will be too broad to be useful.

Instead, people should tag their OS, their Shell (if applicable), and the applicable program/filetype, as this information is much more meaningful and helpful for identifying and categorizing their question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your suggestion of a dedicated sub-tag for Windows Explorer is a good idea.

Maybe the tag could be changed to [explorer-preview-pane](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/explorer-preview-pane) or [windows-explorer-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-explorer-preview)?